# Why is the following statement false

Tags: linear-algebra

> > if an $n \times p$ matrix $U$ has orthonormal columns, then $UU^T\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}$ for all $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbf{R}^n$

So this is my understanding,

if $U$ has orthonormal columns then $U^TU = I$, this is by Theorem A.

Thus $U$ is the inverse of $U^T$ and vice versa, thus $UU^T = U^TU = I$

Therefore $UU^T\mathbf{x} = (UU^T)\mathbf{x} = (I)\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}$

NOTE :

Theorem A : $\quad$
An $m \times n$ matrix $U$ has orthonormal columns if and only if $U^TU = I$

Answer (score 3):

$U$ is not the inverse of $U^{T}$, since $U$ is not a square matrix. That's the mistake in your argument.

Comment: Is there a specific case when $U$ will be the inverse of $U^T$, or does this only occur when $U$ is square? Thank you.

Comment: @darocka Consider $U=\left[\matrix{1\\0}\right]$. Then $U^TU$ is identity, but $UU^T$ is not.

Comment: Only when $U$ is square. If $n\times p$ has orthonormal columns, then necessarily $p\leq n$ (you cannot have more than $n$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$). $UU^{T}$ will be a $n\times n$ matrix, but its rank will be $p$. Hence the only way it is the identity is when $n=p$.